# When bounds are added, the result of scipy.optimize.curve_fit varies when it shouldn't

Tags: python, curve-fitting, least-squares

For the following python script, when I add bounds to the `curve_fit` function, the resulting curve fit is completely different and visibly wrong, even though the parameter that is adjusted for the fit is within the bounds both before and after the bounds are added to the code. Why would this happen?

Here's a link to the data: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bwb0PrDn9o3KZ0lOa1FVZldjV0k/view?usp=sharing

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy import loadtxt, sqrt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit #for least squares curve fit
from scipy import special #for erfc function

plt.rcParams.update({'font.family': "Times New Roman"})
plt.rcParams.update({'font.size': 12})

filename = 'Cr3.csv'

C_b = 17 #base concentration
t_hours = 451
t = t_hours * 3600 #451 hours = 1623600 seconds

data = loadtxt(filename, delimiter=',')
xdata = data[:, 0] #positions
ydata = data[:, 1] #concentration
corr = data[0, 2] #the correction value is manually measured in imagej
xdata = xdata - corr

def func(x, D):
    return C_b/2 * special.erfc(x/(2 * sqrt(D * t))/1e6) #correction for um to m

fig = plt.figure()

plt.plot(xdata, ydata, 'b-', label='data')

popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, xdata, ydata, p0=1e-16)#, bounds=(0,1))

perr = np.sqrt(np.diag(pcov))

plt.plot(xdata, func(xdata, *popt), 'r-',
         label='fit: D = %.2e' % tuple(popt))#, z = %5.3f
plt.xlabel('x (μm)')
plt.ylabel('Cr (wt%)')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Would you please post a link to the data, or (if it is brief) the raw data itself?

Comment: Like @JamesPhillips suggests, please post data.  I might also suggest that you may be close to precision limits, and should recast D to be in microns^2/sec instead of meters^2/sec.  That way the numbers should be more of the scale of (1e-8 to 1e8), which makes the fitting algorithm more stable.  That is, distinguishing 1.e-16 from 0 can be tricky when fitting, as the algorithms will try to take very small steps from that value.

Comment: I added a link to the data in the question description.

Comment: Thank you for posting the data, I can now reproduce the problem.  When I filter the data to remove data points with a y value greater than 30, I do not see this behavior. So the presence of these 12 data points is affecting the problem, though I do not know why.

Comment: Thanks for trying to find the cause. I cannot justify the removal of this data in my research methods. It seems like the `curve_fit` function isn't reliable. Someone might know why but it doesn't help that this question is downvoted.

Comment: scipy.optimize has different fitting algorithms available, perhaps one of those might provide a more stable fit. Your question is interesting as I have never seen this type of behavior from scipy.optimize.curve_fit().

Comment: Unfortunately, we work with scipy version 0.14, so I cannot check your behaviour. Nevertheless, with such simple bounds you can simply redefine your function and write `... sqrt( D**2 / ( 1 + D**2 ) * t )...`. That keeps you inside bounds. Afterwards you just need to do error propagation accordingly. Moreover, with the strong spikes in your data you might think about a different [loss function](http://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/robust_regression.html).